# Desaparece por segundos

Tags: php, html, jquery

alguien me podría ayudar con esto, al darle al botón enviar desaparecen todos los elementos pertenecientes al código por breves segundos y quisiera mostrar la respuesta del calculo fuera del div que esta ocultado pero al sacarlo directamente no me aparecen los formularios del select, soy nuevo asi que perdon el desorden y la falta de conocimiento,( al poner el código aquí en stack directamente no aparece, no creo que sea relevante eso pero si deseo saber el porque desaparece todo lo del código).

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<h1>Estado gaseoso que nesesita encontrar:</h1>
    <form id="formfirst" action="#" method="post">         
    <select id="status" name="status" onChange="mostrar(this.value);">
        <option>Escoja una opcion</option>
        <option value="v1">Volumen1</option>
        <option value="v2">Volumen2</option>
        <option value="p1">Presion1</option>
        <option value="p2">Presion2</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mostrar(id) {
    if (id == "v1") {
        $("#v1").show();
        $("#v2").hide();
        $("#p1").hide();
        $("#p2").hide();
    }

    if (id == "v2") {
        $("#v1").hide();
        $("#v2").show();
        $("#p1").hide();
        $("#p2").hide();
    }

    if (id == "p1") {
        $("#v1").hide();
        $("#v2").hide();
        $("#p1").show();
        $("#p2").hide();
    }

    if (id == "p2") {
        $("#v1").hide();
        $("#v2").hide();
        $("#p1").hide();
        $("#p2").show();
    }
}
</script>
<div id="v1" style="display: none;">
    <h2 id="title1">Si falta volumen uno.</h2>
    
        <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>volumen#2:<br/>
        <input type="number" name="Vol2"  /> Litros</p>
        <p>Presion#1:<br/>
        <input type="number" name="Pre1"  /> Atm</p>
        <p>Presion#2:<br/>
        <input type="number" name="Pre2"  /> Atm</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="send1">
        </form>
        <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
    </form>
        <?php
            $vol2=" ";
            $pre1=" ";
            $pre2=" ";
            

            if($_POST)
            {
                error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
                $vol2 =$_POST["Vol2"];
                $pre1 =$_POST["Pre1"];
                $pre2 =$_POST["Pre2"];
            }
            ?>
            <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send1"])) {
            $vol=($vol2*$pre2)/$pre1;
            echo "El volumen uno es: ".$vol;
                  
            }
         ?>
            
</div>

<div id="v2" style="display: none;">
    <h2 id="title2">Si falta volumen dos.</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>volumen#1<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Vol12" /></p>
        <p>Presion#1:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Pre12" /></p>
        <p>Presion#2:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Pre22" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="send2" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
    <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
    </form>
    <?php
    
            $vol12="";
            $pre12="";
            $pre22="";

            if($_POST)
            {
                $vol12 =$_POST["Vol12"];
                $pre12 =$_POST["Pre12"];
                $pre22 =$_POST["Pre22"];
            }
            ?>
            <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send2"])) {
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
            $vo=($vol12*$pre22)/$pre12; 
            echo"El volumen dos es: ".$vo;                  
            }
         ?>
</div>

<div id="p1" style="display: none;">
    <h2 id="title3">Si falta presion uno.</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>Volumen#1<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Vol13" /></p>
        <p>Volumen#2:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Vol23" /></p>
        <p>Presion#2:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Pre23" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="send3" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
    <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
    </form>
    <?php
            $vol13="";
            $vol23="";
            $pre23="";

            if($_POST)
            {
               $vol13 =$_POST["Vol13"];
               $vol23 =$_POST["Vol23"];
               $pre23 =$_POST["Pre23"];
            }
            ?>
            <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send3"])) {
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
            $pe=($vol23*$pre23)/$vol13; 
            echo "La presion uno es: ".$pe;                 
            }
         ?>
</div>
<div id="p2" style="display: none;">
    <h2 id="title4">Si falta la presion dos.</h2>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <p>Volumen#1<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Vol14" /></p>
        <p>Volumen#2:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Vol24" /></p>
        <p>Presion#1:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="Pre14" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="send4" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
    <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
    </form>
    <?php
            $vol14="";
            $vol24="";
            $pre14="";

            if($_POST)
            {
               $vol14 =$_POST["Vol14"];
               $vol24 =$_POST["Vol24"];
               $pre14 =$_POST["Pre14"];
            }
            ?>
            <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send4"])) {
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
            $pre=($vol14*$pre14)/$vol24; 
            echo "La presion dos es: ".$pre;
            
            }
         ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar  `preventDefault()` para evitar que la página se refresque. Acá te dejo [la documentación.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<h1>Estado gaseoso que nesesita encontrar:</h1>
<form id="formfirst" action="#" method="post">
  <select id="status" name="status" onChange="mostrar(this.value);">
    <option>Escoja una opcion</option>
    <option value="v1">Volumen1</option>
    <option value="v2">Volumen2</option>
    <option value="p1">Presion1</option>
    <option value="p2">Presion2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mostrar(id) {
    if (id == "v1") {
      $("#v1").show();
      $("#v2").hide();
      $("#p1").hide();
      $("#p2").hide();
    }

    if (id == "v2") {
      $("#v1").hide();
      $("#v2").show();
      $("#p1").hide();
      $("#p2").hide();
    }

    if (id == "p1") {
      $("#v1").hide();
      $("#v2").hide();
      $("#p1").show();
      $("#p2").hide();
    }

    if (id == "p2") {
      $("#v1").hide();
      $("#v2").hide();
      $("#p1").hide();
      $("#p2").show();
    }
  }
</script>
<div id="v1" style="display: none;">
  <h2 id="title1">Si falta volumen uno.</h2>

  <form action="#" method="post">
    <p>volumen#2:<br/>
      <input type="number" name="Vol2" /> Litros</p>
    <p>Presion#1:<br/>
      <input type="number" name="Pre1" /> Atm</p>
    <p>Presion#2:<br/>
      <input type="number" name="Pre2" /> Atm</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="send1">
  </form>
  <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
  </form>
  <?php
            $vol2=" ";
            $pre1=" ";
            $pre2=" ";
            

            if($_POST)
            {
                error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
                $vol2 =$_POST["Vol2"];
                $pre1 =$_POST["Pre1"];
                $pre2 =$_POST["Pre2"];
            }
            ?>
    <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send1"])) {
            $vol=($vol2*$pre2)/$pre1;
            echo "El volumen uno es: ".$vol;
                  
            }
         ?>

</div>

<div id="v2" style="display: none;">
  <h2 id="title2">Si falta volumen dos.</h2>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <p>volumen#1<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Vol12" /></p>
    <p>Presion#1:<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Pre12" /></p>
    <p>Presion#2:<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Pre22" /></p>
    <input type="submit" name="send2" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
  <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
  </form>
  <?php
    
            $vol12="";
            $pre12="";
            $pre22="";

            if($_POST)
            {
                $vol12 =$_POST["Vol12"];
                $pre12 =$_POST["Pre12"];
                $pre22 =$_POST["Pre22"];
            }
            ?>
    <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send2"])) {
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
            $vo=($vol12*$pre22)/$pre12; 
            echo"El volumen dos es: ".$vo;                  
            }
         ?>
</div>

<div id="p1" style="display: none;">
  <h2 id="title3">Si falta presion uno.</h2>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <p>Volumen#1<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Vol13" /></p>
    <p>Volumen#2:<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Vol23" /></p>
    <p>Presion#2:<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Pre23" /></p>
    <input type="submit" name="send3" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
  <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
  </form>
  <?php
            $vol13="";
            $vol23="";
            $pre23="";

            if($_POST)
            {
               $vol13 =$_POST["Vol13"];
               $vol23 =$_POST["Vol23"];
               $pre23 =$_POST["Pre23"];
            }
            ?>
    <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send3"])) {
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
            $pe=($vol23*$pre23)/$vol13; 
            echo "La presion uno es: ".$pe;                 
            }
         ?>
</div>
<div id="p2" style="display: none;">
  <h2 id="title4">Si falta la presion dos.</h2>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <p>Volumen#1<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Vol14" /></p>
    <p>Volumen#2:<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Vol24" /></p>
    <p>Presion#1:<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Pre14" /></p>
    <input type="submit" name="send4" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
  <form action="Ejercisiophp.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Resetear" />
  </form>
  <?php
            $vol14="";
            $vol24="";
            $pre14="";

            if($_POST)
            {
               $vol14 =$_POST["Vol14"];
               $vol24 =$_POST["Vol24"];
               $pre14 =$_POST["Pre14"];
            }
            ?>
    <?php
           if (isset($_POST["send4"])) {
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
            $pre=($vol14*$pre14)/$vol24; 
            echo "La presion dos es: ".$pre;
            
            }
         ?>
</div>
```